# How to get sum column with groupby pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I am trying to do a simple thing on dataframe, but I am getting output differently than I expected.

These are parameters and it's values I am getting from called function:

```
context        : ['documentNo']
aggOperation   : sum
aggColumn      : amount
comNewColName  : totalAmountCollected
Result type    : <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index(['Result Columns :\ndocumentNo', 'Result Columns :\ntotalAmountCollected'], dtype='object')
```

Result I am getting:

```
      documentNo                               totalAmountCollected
0      200002692   8,260  1,132,210  80,536  40,120  14,160  1,6...
1      200002699                                  711,093 (711,093)
2      200002700                                         (968) 968 
3      200002764   5,310  62,304  61,124  14,603  75,190  62,658...
4      200002765                                    10,620 (10,620)
```

My groupby code is this:

```
df = sourceDF.groupby(context)[aggColumn].agg(aggOperation).reset_index().rename(columns={'amount':comNewColName})
```

I have to get

```
     documentNo                               totalAmountCollected
0      200002692                                   978979
1      200002699                                   897897
2      200002700                                   968 
3      200002764                                   877899
4      200002765                                   10,620
```

How can I correct my code?

Comment: please provide a DataFrame constructor and code for `aggOperation` for clarity and better explain the logic

Comment: I think problem is with `thousands`, there is `,`, so it is not number but string, so `sum` join strings.

Comment: also some `()` are there.